# What does single quote character and pipe symbol stand for

Tags: oracle, quotes

Consider the following sql-query:

```
SELECT 'delete from TABLE_1 TABLE_1.ID =''' || v.id || ''';'
from TABLE_2 v where v.ID in (select id from TABLE_1);
```

How do you read this syntax?

Comment: I do not think you can select a delete statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single quote character (`'`) starts and ends a string.

The double pipe symbol (`||`) concatenates strings.

As per some comments `||`, is not available with MySQL.

Now, your statement contains even triple quote characters (`'''`). This is because in order to have a single quote character within a (quoted) string, it needs to be escaped by another (preceeding) single quote character.

So: `'foo'` is the string *foo*,`'bar' || ' ' || baz` is the string *bar baz* and `It''s ok` is the string *It's ok*.

The select statement in your question returns a result set constisting of one column whose data type is string. These strings look like so:

```
delete from TABLE_1 TABLE_1.ID ='ABCD';
delete from TABLE_1 TABLE_1.ID ='DEFG';
```

whereas the `ABCD`, `DEFG` ... are the values of `v.id` (that is of table_2 column id).

It looks like your select statement is used to generate delete statements that in turn must somehow be run. Of course, those crated statement won't execute as a `WHERE` is missing.

Comment: That is correct.  The pipes do not work in SQL.  That is only Oracle.

Comment: So what does it mean to select a string?

Comment: @durbnpoisn I think postgres uses || for concatenate as well.

Comment: || is SQL. Only MySQL is not supporting this from my knowledge. -> Mentioned e.g. inside 5.2 of SQL92

Comment: Okay.  Perhaps others like it.  But I know for a fact that SQL Management Studio doesn't like it.  And neither does VS Studio's Business Intelligence.  I work on both SQL and a composite server that uses Oracle.  I need to make sure my syntax is correct depending on the system I'm currently using.